# FBSDKLoginManager log out and log in management

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I am trying to log in using the FB SDK. However, occasionally there is a user who is already logged in. Here is the code below I use to log out first.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

[loginManager logOut];
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
}
```

I am wondering two things:

1) Will the following hit a race condition?
2) If so, should and how would I make the logOut synchronous such that it avoids this condition?

Comment: This is complete speculation, but since a completion block is not specified, I'm guessing that logOut is synchronous. According to the docs, `logOut` calls `[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]` and `[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil]` both of which I would assume to be synchronous.

Comment: What you can achieve in this code? If you really want to logout, you need to logout from safari. FB logout calls just sets everything nil but still the user who logged in is same in safari. And again when you login next time, the same user again gets authorised with same token as far as I observed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution for this problem is to check the `currentAccessToken` is nil or not and manage accordingly.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    // It will be synchronous and will present an alert controller which will further confirm you to logout and will set token and profile to nil.
    [loginManager logOut];
    //after logout you can change your LogOut Button to Login Facebook as done in Facebook samples.
} else { 
    // if the token is nil, just make a login call
    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    }
}
```